# post request help angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, post

I am trying to do a post request to get a token that will let me have access to an access token. Whenever I try to post to it I get an error that the access_token property can't read something that is undefined. I am pretty sure this means that my post request isn't working and I don't know why. I think it has something to do with my post parameters and the map and subscribe methods. I just don't know how to fix them. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

This is my code for the post request.

```
httpPostRequest() {
    this.grabState();
    this.grabCode();
    this.grabSessionStorage();
    this.grabTokenUri();
    this.grabClientId();
    this.grabSecret();
    this.grabServiceUri();
    this.grabRedirectUri();
    this.data = {
      code: this.code,
      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
      redirect_uri: this.redirectUri,
    };
    const headers = new Headers({'Accept': 'application/json'});
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this._http.post(this.tokenUri, this.data, options)
      .map((postResponse: Response) => postResponse.json())
      .subscribe(resPostResponse => (this.postResponseJson = resPostResponse));
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular `HttpClient` is *asynchronous*, so you have to subscribe to your post request (in your view for example).It's now returning `undefined` because it's not executed yet. You can use a callback to execute an another function after getting the token.

Comment: Thanks man. That's exactly what I needed help with. I found out that my post request was written right and should work, but I could never get it to work right. I'll see what I can do.